# Does monster health scale on multiplayer accordingly to number of players?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Does any given monster have <number of players> x <base health> on multiplayer sessions? Besides having multiple skills and buffs, will hunting with friends take approximately the same time as hunting alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monster health does **not** scale according to the number of players. However, monsters in Tanzia Port have more health than Monsters fought in the Moga Village. iCEMANnoob did a video to prove this a ways back, as you can see below. He fought a Great Jaggi in the Village (19 hits), along with a Great Jaggi in Tanzia Port solo (24 hits) and in a group of four (23 hits).

Answer (score 4):

No. Monsters do not scale to the number of players hunting. Nothing scales to the number of players involved, which shortens the length of hunts considerably. Anecdotally, I've done 5 minute Gold Rathian and Silver Rathalos runs.